# Java Get substring of a string

Tags: java, string

I have 2 strings as shown below:

```
String paramNum = "99999256";
String opCode = "99999";
```

On the `String paramNum` I want to extract that part of the string which appears after the string value contained in `opCode`

So with the above example: the result should be `"99999256"` - `"99999"` = `"256"`.
Parse `paramNum` (`99999256`) and reach to a position of after `99999` and then do a substring till end of the string. But I am not sure on how to reach to that position?

Note this is only a symbolic representation of what I want to do with these strings and they do mean a subtraction on 2 int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of 100+ possible ways:

```
String res = paramNum.replace(opCode,"");
```

Visit the [`String API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to fuel your creative fire.

If you want to replace only first match, you can:

```
String res = paramNum.replaceFirst(opCode,"");
```

Comment: probably easiest of 'em all.

Comment: Tricky because if `opCode` appears multiple times in the string, all occurrences will be replaced.

Comment: What if 99999 appears in the second half?

Comment: With `replaceFirst` you should use `Pattern.quote` just in case `opCode` would contain smth like `a+b+c`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Indeed. I think my answer guides OP enough. He can easily investigate and learn from here.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I like the replace method... though I may be doing what the replace would be doing internally (find it and extract it)

Answer (score 1):

Using `String#substring`:

```
int indexOfOpCode = paramNum.indexOf(opCode);
if(indexOfOpCode != -1) {
    String extractedStr = paramNum.substring(indexOfOpCode + opCode.length());
    ...
}
```

Comment: or use [`StringUtils.substringAfter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

I came with the below:

```
if (paramNum.startsWith(opCode)) { // This can be - if (paramNum.contains(opCode)) {
   String res = paramNum.substring(opCode.length(), paramNum.length());
}
```

Note that for my case the string that I want to find always appears at the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

One of the way:

String opcode;

String res= paranum.replaceAll(opcode," ");

Will replace all the occurrence of opcode string with space...whereas in place of opcode you can also 
give regular expression as a string...